# What does "dick" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm a bit confused about the meaning of "dick" in the following context. Girl comes to pub and wants to participate in a pool tournament. She is told, that "it's men only".

> Everyone is looking now. I can’t back down, and now that I’m
> being challenged, I want to prove myself. I take a cue from the rack. There are some balls scattered
> on the table, a few reds, and all the colours. I drop down and aim
> for a red near the cushion. It rattles the jaw of the pocket, and
> there’s a collective holding of breath as it drops. I pot the black
> ball and straighten up.
> ‘So what do I need to show?’ I say. ‘**A dick,** or a minimum level
> of competency?

Lauren Westwood "My mother's silence"

I guess, she asks if "a dick" is the only "ticket" to this tournament, but what does "minimum level of competency" mean then? Google directs me to Dick Lane and Dick Jaspers as pool players, but, suppose, they have nothing to do with this situation :D  Absolutely confused about this sentence :(:(

Comment: The reference is not to pool, but to the 'men only' rule!

Comment: It's vulgar slang.

Comment: The description of the balls sounds more like snooker than pool.

Comment: If you read the book, you will find that it indeed _is_ a snooker table, not a pool table, albeit larger than tournament size.

Comment: Dick=male. Or vice versa, depending on perspective :-).

Comment: James K, JdeBP: Here's the excerpt:  Then, there’s a loud cheer from
upstairs where, according to a banner above the door to the toilets,
a pool tournament is going on."

Comment: Check all meanings, and see which fits: "Dick" = short for "Richard" (but capital letter!), and "private dick" = "private detective/investigator" (nope!), or it's the other meaning here (with "to have"), or by extension "[any private part] +to be" = "annoying person". (And the parts can be male: d$ck/ d$ckhead/.. neutral: $ss/ $rsehole/... or female: c$nt/ tw$t/... although female seems british preference?).

Comment: @KristinaLukosevice, the sign may have announced a pool tournament, but when she goes upstairs she finds the pool tables replaced by a snooker table. They are definitely playing snooker.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I agree with @rjpond. I'll just answer in a slightly different way by translating rather than explaining!

> So what do I need to show?’ ... ‘A dick, or a minimum level of competency?

*What is more important for me to display in order to be admitted?* *A penis? Or that my skill is higher than the minimum required level.*

Answer (score 50):

They've told her that the tournament is male-only.

She challenges this by displaying her competence and then demanding whether showing a minimum level of competence is sufficient or whether they are still going to insist she needs a male anatomy ("dick", penis).

Lexico defines "dick" as follows:

> *vulgar slang* A man's penis.
> https://www.lexico.com/definition/dick

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning the inference that the pub patrons believe her gender, by definition, indicates a lower level of competence.

Comment: Although reading the book reveals that the issue is that the tournament is sex-segregated and the women's competition has just finished.

Comment: @JdeBP Usually sex-segregated competitions imply that one sex would be less able to compete than the other, so they are giving a separate competition so they can compete with peers--kind of like creating a major and minor league, except that instead of separating by ability they have chosen to separate by a physical attribute with the (perhaps not intentional) implication that *all* of one sex are less able than the other...there is no way one sex would be capable enough to compete in the "major league". (For pool it would definitely be implied that women are less able than men.)

Comment: As I said, one can read the book and find out what's _actually written_, instead of as you have just done inventing, wholesale, implications of one's own that are not based upon the novel that the questioner is trying to understand.

Comment: The question asks for the meaning of the sentence explicitly referencing the context of the given paragraph.  'Meaning-in-context' doesn't (and shouldn't) require a reading of the entire publication.  Also, your additional information doesn't alter the answer.  About the only valid reason for gender discrimination in sport is muscular strength which is not required to play pool.  In context, the "wholesale invented' implications fit.  Including the fact that there's a separate female tournament doesn't change this.

Comment: It's not the answer that is altered, it is _your_ insistence in inventing your own implications from whole cloth, and having them added to the answer.  You're even doing it _again_, insisting that your own inventions "fit" into a novel that you haven't read.

Comment: @user3067860 While this is logically true, there is still a separate woman league for chess.

Comment: @JdeBP Does it explain in the book why the competitions are sex-segregated? Specifically, why it was chosen to separate based on sex as opposed to based on "likes chocolate" and "doesn't like chocolate" or any other arbitrary division? (Or even a meaningful division, such as "participated in x number of competitions at this level" vs new player.) If you think it's absurd to split a chess tournament based on liking chocolate but it's reasonable to split it based on having a penis, I think you're making my case better than I can.

Comment: @JdeBP: your point and @ mcalex’s both seem useful, not in contradiction with each other at all.  It’s helpful to know about the context from the novel; but @ mcalex’s point is also very relevant, as a background cultural expectation which the book is assuming most readers will be familiar with, but which a non-anglophone reader may well be unfamiliar with.  The fact that the book then subverts the expectation doesn’t mean the expectation is irrelevant — indeed, quite the contrary.